# RSTempFiles - Linking Them To A Specific Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there any way to identify which report/subscription caused an RSTempFile to be written?  We have had a few sizeable ones recently, and short of matching approximate file times with the runs in the execution log, its hard to say exactly which report run caused it.

The file names all contain some soft of UniqueIdentifier but it doesn't link back to report/subscriptionID.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS##.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\RSTempFiles

Thanks,
Ralph